# Passing a method as a parameter

Tags: ruby

Is there are way to pass a method as a parameter without using a `Proc` object or block? The answers I've seen to similar questions rely on creating a `Proc` object.

```
def call_a_method_via_a_parameter( &some_method )
  # ?? call some_method and pass it a parameter ??
end
def my_method( param )
  puts param
end

call_a_method_via_a_parameter( &:my_method )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def bob(jeff)
  puts "hi #{jeff}"
end

def mary(meth, params)
  meth.call(params)
end

mary(method(:bob), 'yo')
=> hi yo
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby is an object-oriented language. You can only pass around and manipulate objects, but methods aren't objects, ergo, you cannot pass them around.

You *can*, however, ask Ruby to give you a proxy object for a method via the `Object#method` method, which will return a `Method` object (which duck-types `Proc`):

```
def call_a_method_via_a_parameter(some_method)
  some_method.('Hi')
end

def my_method(param)
  puts param
end

call_a_method_via_a_parameter(method(:my_method))
# Hi
```

An alternative would be to pass the *name* of the method as a `Symbol`:

```
def call_a_method_via_a_parameter(some_method)
  public_send(:some_method, 'Hi')
end

def my_method(param)
  puts param
end

call_a_method_via_a_parameter(:my_method)
# Hi
```

So, in short: no, you cannot pass the method, but you *can* pass either the *name* of the method or a proxy object for the method.

However, the *idiomatic* way would be to use a block:

```
def call_a_method_via_a_parameter
  yield 'Hi'
end

def my_method(param)
  puts param
end

call_a_method_via_a_parameter(&method(:my_method))
# Hi
```